# File existence with monit

Tags: linux, monit

Does `monit`blocks until file exists in the specified path? I have a shell script which checks for file existence in a `while loop` and then execute a binary. How can I use `monit` to avoid the while loop?

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ ! -f /root/initt ]
do
sleep 1
echo "waiting for /root/initt"
done

echo "initt done"
/usr/bin/myprocess &
```

Comment: Not sure if `monit` can do that, but to me installing it for this purpose would seem like overkill if a simple `touch /root/initt &&  inotifywait -e close_write /root/initt` would do.

Comment: okay.  I thought `monit` will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: So you'd be happy with that as an answer to your question, even though it doesn't involve `monit`?

Comment: Hmm No.. I was aware  inotify would do but I'm looking for monit solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
check file initt with path /root/initt
    if exist then exec "nohup /usr/bin/myprocess </dev/null >/dev/null &"
```